# How are varieties related polynomials?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, soft-question, terminology, ideals

My teacher says that varieties and ideals are related to each other while I tend to mix polynomials and varieties in my terminology. Could some explain how varieties are related to polynomials? And why it is important not to mix varieties and polynomials together?

Comment: Varieties are sets of solutions to equation systems of polynomials. So the solutions to a bunch of polynomials, each simultaneously = 0.

Comment: And the solutions to a system of polynomials are also solutions to all the polynomials in the ideal generated by the polynomials in the system.